# Configure IOptions<T> with ServiceCollection when T is Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I need to register an `IOptions<T>` with a .NET Core `ServiceCollection`.

Normally the method would be something like this:

```
var configSection = configuration.GetSection("sectionName");
serviceCollection.Configure<KnownClassName>(configSection);
```

This registers a strongly typed `IOptions<KnownClassName>` with the container.

I need to register an `IOptions<UnknownName>`.  I have the `Type` of the class. I can't seem to find a method that will allow me to register the `Type` and the configuration section.

This is what am attempting to do:

```
interface ILoggingProvider
{
    Type GetSettingType();
    string ProviderName {get;}
}

IList<ILoggingProvider> loggingProviders = GetLoggingProviders();

foreach(var provider in loggingProvider)
{
    var providerSection = configuration.GetSection(providerSection);
    var providerSettingType = provider.GetSettingType();

    // can't find an overload or other method to do the same thing as 
    // serviceCollection.Configure<LoggerSettings>(providerSection);

    serviceCollection.Configure(providerSection, providerSettingType);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this is possible; checking [the source of `IServiceCollection.Configure<TOptions>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions/src/OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L57) shows that the entire options/configuration functionality is built around generic types.

Also, as far as I know, there is no non-generic `IOptions` interface, so there is not really a justification for providing a non-generic configuration registration method.

---

However, this implies that your `ILoggingProvider` instances have to make use of `IOptions<UnknownName>` themselves, else they would not be able to retrieve the configuration from the DI container. In this case, you may either expose the options class of the particular providers, or add an (extension-)method `ILoggingProvider.RegisterOptions(IServiceCollection, IConfiguration)` which does this registration itself.

In Startup.cs, you would then simply call

```
provider.RegisterOptions(serviceCollection, providerSection);
```

for each provider.

This of course requires write access to the source code of the `ILoggingProvider` implementations.

Comment: I considered this.  In fact it is one of two options I have remaining if I couldn't find a way to use a Type to configure the IOptions<T>.  My problem is the separation of concerns (or lack of).  the ILoggingProvider - more specifically the GetProviderType() method is in the base class.  While this accomplishes the task, it bothers me that my base LoggingProvider class now provides methods for logging support and service registration. I am going to implement an extension method for each derived provider; allowing me to call serviceCollection.Configure<NowIHaveTheType>(config);

Answer (score 1):

You could use `services.ConfigureOptions`, if it is possible to return type that implements `IConfigureOptions<T>` from your `ILoggingProvider.GetSettingType()`

```
public class CustomConfiguration
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}

public class CustomConfigurationOptions : IConfigureOptions<CustomConfiguration>
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public CustomConfigurationOptions(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void Configure(CustomConfiguration options)
    {
        var optionsFromConfig = configuration
            .GetSection(nameof(CustomConfiguration))
            .Get<CustomConfiguration>();

        options.Data = optionsFromConfig.Data;
    }
}

public class LoggingProvider
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
}

public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();

        var loggingProviders = new List<LoggingProvider>()
        {
            new LoggingProvider()
            {
                Type = typeof(CustomConfigurationOptions)
            }
        };

        foreach (var loggingProvider in loggingProviders)
        {
            services.ConfigureOptions(loggingProvider.Type);
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is I don't know <CustomConfiguration> in the base logger class.  It is a generic type, that is why I exposed the GetSettingsType() method.

Comment: you dont need to know it in the base class, options types will be returned from implementations